# how can we increase the string limit or size for base64Encode

Tags: jmeter, base64, jmeter-5.0

[[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ElYMm.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iqUDy.png)

I tried to pass a string from csv file to ${__base64Encode()} function but in result my API request is getting failed. When I checked my jmeter logs then in that I found that base64Encode function is unable to encode the string because it is too long and limit is 65535. So, is there any way by which I can increase the string limit to encode my string or is there other way because I need to pass that string to initially encode the data to make my script work.

Please find the attached screenshot for the error in mentioned link and let me know if there is any solution to resolve this issue.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0):

Don't inline [JMeter Functions or Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) in Groovy scripts, as per [JSR223 Sampler documentation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler):

> The JSR223 test elements have a feature (compilation) that can significantly increase performance. To benefit from this feature:
>
> - Use Script files instead of inlining them. This will make JMeter compile them if this feature is available on ScriptEngine and cache them.
> - Or Use Script Text and check Cache compiled script if available property.
>
> When using this feature, **ensure your script code does not use JMeter variables or JMeter function calls directly in script code as caching would only cache first replacement.** Instead use script parameters.

Amend your code to look like:

```
vars.put('token', vars.get('token1').bytes.encodeBase64().toString())
```

and the error should go away

More information on Groovy scripting in JMeter: [Apache Groovy: What Is Groovy Used For?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy)

Alternatively just use [`${__base64Encode(${token1},token)}` function](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/Functions/#base64Encodesupfont-color-gray-size-1-since-1-2-0-font-sup) where required, **but not in the JSR223 Test Element script**